# Authenticate WP REST API GET Requests

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

Recently I have installed WP REST API on my site and it is working pretty well. But the problem is that the data is accessbile to the public over the open URLs which doesn't reguire authentication. For example a get request to wp-json/wp/v2/posts lists all the post detail to the users.

Is there any way to authenticate the GET Requests to WordPress REST API? I don't want this data is available to anonymous users. Even a basic authentication should work for me!

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: As I didn't find the exact solution, I have written a code to fetch data from the WordPress database and keep in a json file when a post is modified. it is protected with a basic API key authentication

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a filter in the `/wp-includes/default-filters.php`

Find this section:

```
// REST API filters.
add_action( 'xmlrpc_rsd_apis',            'rest_output_rsd' );
add_action( 'wp_head',                    'rest_output_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'template_redirect',          'rest_output_link_header', 11, 0 );
add_action( 'auth_cookie_malformed',      'rest_cookie_collect_status' );
add_action( 'auth_cookie_expired',        'rest_cookie_collect_status' );
add_action( 'auth_cookie_bad_username',   'rest_cookie_collect_status' );
add_action( 'auth_cookie_bad_hash',       'rest_cookie_collect_status' );
add_action( 'auth_cookie_valid',          'rest_cookie_collect_status' );
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', 'rest_cookie_check_errors', 100 );
```

Then add a new filter like so:

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            return $result;
        }
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', 'You are not currently logged in.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
        }
        return $result;
    });
```

This solution is [mentioned on the WordPress developer resources site](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#can-i-disable-the-rest-api), but they do not specifically tell you where to add the filter.

After this change, you should see this message when an un-authenticated user attempts to connect to the REST API:

`{"code":"rest_not_logged_in","message":"You are not currently logged in.","data":{"status":401}}`

Comment: You certainly do not want to edit anything in wp-includes manually since it might be overriden with the next WP update ...

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict WP REST API only for logged users with this plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-json-api/

or if you don't want use plugin you can add this code in your theme

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', 'ultimatewoo_disable_rest_api' );
function disable_rest_api( $access ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'rest_disabled', __( 'The REST API on this site has been disabled.' ), array( 'status' => rest_authorization_required_code() ) );
}}
```

Comment: Hello Ryan AW,

Thanks for your answer. I'm fetching the details from WordPress to my mobile application via REST API, I want the REST to be accessible only for my mobile application(Even get request). Is there any option?

Comment: my 2nd answer is worked even for get request. Add that code within your function. Let me know if it's worked for your or now @Abdussamad

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to restrict by ip

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', 'filter_incoming_connections' );

function filter_incoming_connections( $errors ){

  $allowedAddress = array( '127.0.0.1' );
  $requestServer = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  if( ! in_array( $requestServer, $allowedAddress ) )
    return new WP_Error( 'forbidden_access', 'Access denied', array( 'status' => 403 ) );

  return $errors;
}
```

$allowedAddress add authorized ip

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change that code with this one.

```
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
    return $result;
}
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'restx_logged_out', 'Sorry, you must be logged in to make a request.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
}
return $result;
});
```